# What's the substitution of <codecvt> in C++17 or later?

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, standards, c++17

According to [this article](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2017/03/27/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-kona-february-2017/) and [P0618R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html), the header `<codecvt>` has been deprecated in C++17.

I have been used it heavily. So I want to know:

**What's the substitution of `<codecvt>` in C++17 or later?**

Comment: currently? non. encoding has always being a sore problem in C++

Comment: Guess that will be *"or later"*. Deprecated generally means "avoid using this as it is not good, and might get replaced later". On the other hand, we have `strstream` which was deprecated already in C++98, and is still there in C++17.

Comment: Don't panic. Formally, deprecation **only** means that the deprecated feature **might** be removed sometime in the future. In itself that's not a reason to stop using the feature. For example, the standard C libraries have been deprecated in C++ for more than 20 years, but they're not going away.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, there is even [a recent proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0619r0.html#3.5) to undeprecate the C headers (and remove useless C++ wrappers like `<ccomplex>`). The reason being the same a for the undeprecation of `static` functions: even if C++ has better alternatives, C compatibility matters and compatibility features shouldn't be deprecated.

Comment: I read this question as 'what is the proposal emerging from the committee' nowadays? Meening, which external lib is the best candidate for replacement?